# A function that's ω(1) but o(log^(k) n)?

Tags: function, math, time-complexity

I am working on asymptotic relations in my book for an interview but I do not understand one question.

> Give an example of a function which is o(log<sup>(k)</sup> n) for any fixed k, but which is ω(1).

What function is of this form but is also ω(1)?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to ask in this question.

Comment: I want to come up with a function that if of the o(log^(k) n) but is also small omega(1). I am confused about this. :\

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions of this form.

The function log<sup>(k + 1)</sup> n is ω(1) because it still grows, just really slowly. On the other hand, it's also o(log<sup>(k)</sup> n) because it has another logarithm applied.

Another example of a function of this sort is the [iterated logarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) log* n and the unbelievably slowly-growing [Ackermann inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Ackermann#Inverse) α(n).

More generally, there is no slowest-growing function. As a way of seeing this, consider any function f(n) that's ω(1). The function log f(n) then grows even more slowly than f(n) does, so it will be o(f(n)) but still ω(1) because f(n) = ω(1).

Hope this helps!